# C Eclipse - Printing unwanted unicode characters when reading file

Tags: c, eclipse

I am a beginner at C, and am trying to read a text file containing only Hello world character by character.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
FILE *fin = fopen("t1.txt", "r");
char temp = fgetc(fin);
printf("%c", temp);
while (temp != EOF) {
    temp = fgetc(fin);
    printf("%c", temp);
}
fclose(fin);
```

However, the output is Hello worldÿ . I have added a new line at the end of Hello world and the ÿ shows up after it. I've used this code to traverse and print out a text file filled with int without problems, but changing from %d to %c causes a similarly strange character to print. I have been told that this is a local issue, potentially related to Eastern languages on my PC or the new Eclipse update. What may be the issue here, and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  Cramming the `int` that comes from `fgetc()` into a `char` value makes detection of `EOF` unreliable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That was it, thank you so much!

Comment: And you print the EOF before your `while` finds that it is EOF.

Comment: @thebusybee Sorry, do you mind elaborating on 'printing the EOF'? If the file isn't empty, wouldn't temp be equal to a character? And the while loop would start getting characters starting from the 2nd file character

Comment: Look at your loop: Assumed that the last read character is no `EOF`, it executes its body. So it calls `fgetc()` and happens to read `EOF` because it's at the end of the input. **Now it prints `EOF`,** and only after that it checks the loop condition again.

Comment: @thebusybee Oh, I got it. Thank you very much, this is good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
FILE *fin = fopen("t1.txt", "r");
int temp;
while ((temp = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", temp);
}
fclose(fin);
```

I find it easiest and least confusing to read the character in the `while` statement, as shown above. This allows more concise code, and it prevents you from printing the `EOF` character, as was mentioned in the comments.

As also mentioned in the comments, `fgetc()` returns and `int`, not a `char`, so I made that change here as well.

If I may, I'd also like to point out that `temp` is a rather bad name for a variable because it's not very descriptive. Perhaps consider using something even like `c`, which is simple. It's short, and generally makes it known that you're dealing with a character (though it's technically an `int`)

Comment: Thank you! The assignment inside the while loop allowed it to run.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by assigning `(temp = fgetc(fin)) != EOF`.